# Can an Outlook add-in create a Cookie

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created a outlook add-in after authenticating the user i need to store an access key in a cookie. My question is can an outlook add-in create cookies and if so how ?.

Below is my code, document.cookie is always an empty string and no cookies have been created when i inspect element. I am developing in Outlook web

```
//call back mehtod
function processMessage(arg) {

    dialog.close();
    var tokens = JSON.parse(arg.message);

    //Create Cookie
    //document.cookie = "Test" + "=" + "Key" + ";sameSite=none";
    //document.cookie = "Test" + "=" + "Key" + ";SameSite=Strict;Secure";
    document.cookie = "Test" + "=" + "Key" + ";";

    //Get Cookies
    console.log("cookie");
    console.log(document.cookie);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [Edge destroys session cookie on pane closing.](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1708). Here is the sample code which can be used for dealing with cookies in Office web add-ins:

```
    // Stores the settings as a browser cookie.
    function saveToBrowserCookies(key, value) {

        document.cookie = key + "=" + value;
    }

    // Retrieves the specified setting from the browser cookies.
    function getFromBrowserCookies(key) {
        var cookies = {};
        var all = document.cookie;
        var value = null;

        if (all === "") { return cookies }
        else {
            var list = all.split("; ");
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                var cookie = list[i];
                var p = cookie.indexOf("=");
                var name = cookie.substring(0, p);

                if (name == key) {
                    value = cookie.substring(p + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return value;
    }
```

Read more about all techniques described in depth in the [Persist add-in state and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings) article. You can find these techniques implemented in the [StorageLibrary.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-PersistCustomSettings/blob/master/PersistCustomSettingsWeb/App/Home/StorageLibrary.js) file.

But I'd suggest using the [Office.RoamingSettings interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-preview) for such tasks. The settings created by using the methods of the RoamingSettings object are saved per add-in and per user. That is, they are available only to the add-in that created them, and only from the user's mailbox in which they are saved.

While the Outlook add-in API limits access to these settings to only the add-in that created them, these settings shouldn't be considered secure storage. They can be accessed by Exchange Web Services or Extended MAPI. They shouldn't be used to store sensitive information, such as user credentials or security tokens.

Comment: Hello, thanks again for your help and I will look into using Office.RoamingSettings. With regards to the Cookies. I am not able to create cookies in edge, firefox or chrome but I am able to create cookies when running my add-in in the Outlook desktop app. What I would like to know if anyone knows is should it be possible for me to create cookies in an Outlook add-in on the web or is this a bug with all outlook add-ins or am I doing something wrong/ I'm I missing anything.

Comment: Have you checked the issues with cookies I mentioned in my post?

Comment: Yes I have checked it, sorry I may have misunderstood but what they are talking about in the link is "Edge destroys session cookie on pane closing". My Issue that I am not able to create any cookies on edge, firefox or chrome but I can on the Outlook Desktop app. I am looking for some clarification around whether I should be able to create cookies is an Outlook web Add-in or not. Or is it that this is now not reliable in Outlook Web because of changes to how some browsers are now handling them ? again thanks for your help

Comment: I'd suggest posting such problems/issues to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Comment: Office js support some of the techniques for storage and all are listed in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings .Please try to use it and let us know if it helps